# One of two flask apps deployed on the same server with unresponsive '/' route

Tags: python, nginx, flask, deployment

## Problem

I have two flask applications deployed to the same GCP compute engine with an nginx server.

The first app on the main domain: `myapp.com.`

The second is on a subdomain: `example.myapp.com.`

All the routes from the first app on the main domain are accessible and render their views properly, however the '/' route from the second app just hangs, and eventually returns a timeout error. The strange part is, if I visit other routes explicitly on the second app, for example: `example.myapp.com/about-example` or `example.myapp.com/home`, the page renders immediately.

I tested all the routes on the second app, they all work. The default home route `/` is the only one causing the issue when I navigate to `example.myapp.com`

## Project structure

Apps are deployed on the user directory

```bash
home
    └── user1
        ├── app1
        └── app2
```

## NGINX

I removed the default conf from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and added these additional confs for each app

### App1 conf

```
server {
    server_name myapp.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app1.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app1.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/user1/app1/app/static;
    }
}
```

### App2 conf

```
server {
    server_name example.myapp.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app2.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app2.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/user1/app2/app/src/static;
    }
}
```

## Deployment

I use gunicorn along with supervisor to run the apps. Each application gets a supervisor conf. stored at /etc/supervisor/conf.d/(name-of-app)-supervisor.conf. Verified supervisord is reading in the additional conf properly.

### App1 supervisor conf

```ini
[program:app1]
command=/home/user1/app1/venv/bin/gunicorn personal_website:app -w 2
directory=/home/user1/app1
user=user1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/app1/app1.out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/app1/app1.err.log
```

### App2 supervisor conf

```ini
[program:app2]
command=/home/user1/app2/venv/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8001 run:app
directory=/home/user1/app2
user=user1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/app2.out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/app2.err.log
```

## Flask routes

Application is organized as a package using blueprints

### app2

location: `app/src/main/routes.py`

```py
"""Main blueprint module"""
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

main = Blueprint("main", __name__)

@main.route("/")
@main.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html", active_page="home")
```

## Flask app configuration

There is more stuff going on in this `__init__` file but removed it for brevity

location: `app/src/__init__.py`

```py
from flask import Flask

from app.config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    from app.src.users.routes import users
    from app.src.entries.routes import entries
    from app.src.main.routes import main

    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(entries)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    return app
```

Appreciate any advice and feedback. I know there are a lot of moving pieces here and this is a bit messy but I am at my wits end here. Let me know if I have missed any pieces to help make the question more understandable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating two Flask app instances in **init**.py, the module-level Flask app instance is not used in your `create_app()` this might cause your problem because of the routes.

Try this code

```
from flask import Flask

from app.config import Config

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    from app.src.users.routes import users
    from app.src.entries.routes import entries
    from app.src.main.routes import main

    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(entries)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    return app
```

and also be sure that you use `create_app()` function correctly when starting your app with `Gunicorn`

in your `run.py` it must be something like that:

```
from app.src import create_app

app = create_app()
```

If you still have error check the logs of `Nginx` and `Supervisor`, try to reproduce your errors localy.

Comment: Appreciate the answer @Saxtheowl. I provisioned a new vm and went through my deployment again to apply this suggestion, however the apps worked fine even with the double app creation (good catch, thanks) I'm going to move the app instantiation at the module level and remove the call in the method anyways. It must have been some glitch with the vm or the nginx server.